# How can I find out the width and height of a modal dialog with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="modal">
   <div class="block-border" style="width: 900px; height: 450px;">
   xxx
   </div>
</div>
```

I am trying this script:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
var modal_width = modal.width;
var modal_height = modal.height;
var window_width = window.width;
var window_height = window.height;
modal.style.left = window_width / 2 - modal_width / 2;
modal.style.top = window_height / 2 - modal_height / 2;
```

When I check the modal variable it looks correct. However the modal_width and modal_height variables show undefined. I tried moving the width and height style to the first div but I still can't find the width and height.

Comment: If you want to get the width as defined by the style, it'd be `modal.style.width` (but keep in mind you'd need to parse out the numbers, because it will come with the unit). Otherwise, you might want `modal.offsetWidth` for its full width (including padding, border, etc).

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - that sounds like an answer to me. Make it as such and get your rep points.

Comment: Thanks but is there still no value even if it is defined by the style. I also noticed that window.width and window.height are not working.

Comment: You have no ID on your modal box, that's why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On second thought, that comment of mine is an answer :p It wasn't supposed to be!

There are a few different definitions of "width", which is why elements don't just have `width`.

You can of course get the width as defined by the style: `modal.style.width` - however, keep in mind that it will come back with the unit attached, so you would probably need to run it through
`parseInt(modal.style.width,10)`. Also, this does not include any padding or border styles, which would be needed if you're using `.left`... unless you also have `box-sizing:border-box`, and also it only works for inline styles (which you shouldn't be using).

Overall, you're probably better with `modal.offsetWidth`. This width always includes the border the padding, and is useful for centering.

That said, consider a pure CSS solution:

```
.modal>div {
    width:900px;
    height:450px;
    position:absolute; /* or "fixed", depending on the desired effect */
    left:0; top:0; right:0; bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```

All being well, this should perfectly center your modal box, regardless of content size. Well... maybe you might run into problems if the content is bigger than the screen, but in most cases, it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById('modal')` 
wont work in this case because there is no `id='modal'` at all ... there is only a class named 'modal'

try `document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[0]` instead ...